# ActivatedRoute in Angular 5 not delivering URL parameters. Ideas?

Tags: angular, url, get, angular5, angular-activatedroute

I have implemented ActivatedRoute on my app.component.ts page. This is the page where I have a big, red exit button on, and it appears on all pages of my app as intended.

I jump into the url I've created (with a query string) as follows:

`http://localhost:4200/status?returnString=xyz`

I have a `private route: ActivatedRoute` within my constructor. In my `ngOnInit()` function I have `console.log(this.route.queryParams);`. And that returns an object where the `._value` is an object with a property of `returnString: "xyz"` as intended.

The problem is, when I `console.log(this.route.queryParams.returnString)` or `console.log(this.route.queryParams._value)` I am being served an object with no properties. `{}`.

My question is, what happened or moreover, what am I doing wrong? What will it take for me to get a parameter from the URL that I can consume in Angular 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is due to the fact that `queryParams` is an `Observable`.

In your `ngOnInit()` function you need to subscribe to the observable:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route. queryParams.subscribe(
      params => {//Do something with the params.returnString},
      err => console.log(err)
);
}
```

[Official Angular Docs - ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute)

Answer (score 1):

[queryParams](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#queryParams) is an Observable, so you should listen to changes instead of inspecting the value.

When app.component is initiated the value isn't set yet, but when you inspect it, it is. That's probably what you are experiencing.

Set up a listener and react to changes instead

```
route.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => this.doSomething(params.returnString))
```